# Few questions about jqtouch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jqtouch

I am using Rails 3. Consider the following code listed at bottom.

1) Should links to other actions be done via href (href="/foo/bar") or via #id (id="#foobar_div")? In some document I read online. Providing an actual link to the href attribute tells the iPhone to execute an AJAX call.

If I provide an div#id instead, then it loads the page without ajax (the same way browsers do this). However, providing div#id's means that all content has to be declared a single page.

Whats the right way for calling other pages on the server?

2) Is there anything wrong with the code structure below? i.e. can I style my own span elements like this?

3) The [demo pages](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/blob/master/demos/main/index.html) indicate that all content should be in one page. However, Ryan Bates from railscast.com has an [episode](http://media.railscasts.com/videos/199_mobile_devices.mov) about jqtouch and his pages are separate. which is the proper way?

```
<ul>
  <% @songs.each do |song| %>
    <li class="arrow">
      <%= link_to(song_path(song)) do %>
        <%= image_tag(song.user.profile_image, :alt => 'profile image', :style => 'float:left;') %>
        <span class="title"><%= song.title %></span>
        <span class="artist">by <%= song.user.first_name %></span>
        <span class="likes"><%= song.likes.count %> loves</span>
      <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first and third questions (which to me are the asking the same thing), it depends on the project you're working on.

If you're providing static contents, you can just load all the pages in one hit, hence using "id=#foobar_div", as long as there are not that many pages (as you don't want the users to hold the phone and look stupid in front of their friends waiting 30 minutes for your site to load).

If you're providing dynamic contents or there are too many pages for your site, you may want to use the AJAX approach, at least for some pages.

At the bottom line, you want to load as many static pages as possible while still keeping your site responsive.

For question 2, I'm not quite sure I got what you're asking. I can't see anything obviously wrong, but again, I'm not a rail programmer.